# How to create a swift object given the classname "EKAttendee"

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift2

Given the following objective c code

```
Class className = NSClassFromString(@"EKAttendee");
id attendee = [className new];
```

what would the swift code be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that shows how to use `NSClassFromString`:

```
if let clazz = NSClassFromString("NSView") as? NSView.Type {
    let v = clazz.init(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    print(v.frame) // (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code

I copied this into it

```
Class className = NSClassFromString(@"EKAttendee");
id attendee = [className new];
```

and I got back this

```
var className: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("EKAttendee")
var attendee: AnyObject = className()
```

Comment: I'm getting error: 'AnyObject' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
        var attendee: AnyObject = className()

Comment: Thanks for the link to the convertor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
let anyObjectType : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("EKAttendee")!
let nsObjectType : NSObject.Type = anyObjectType as! NSObject.Type
var attendee: AnyObject = nsObjectType.init() 

print("\(attendee)")
```

Results

```
EKAttendee <0x51763530>
email               : (null)
isCurrentUser       : 0
replyRequested      : 0
role                : (null)
status              : (null)
type                : 0
scheduleForceSend   : 0
```