# How to set email for a EKAttendee object in swift

Tags: macos, swift2

I want to add some attendees to an EKEvent object.

I'm using [this solution written in objective c as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627694/modifying-ekparticipants-attendees-in-eventkit-like-sunrise)

So far I've got this [from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050308/how-to-create-a-swift-object-given-the-classname-ekattendee/35052229#35052229)

```
var anyObjectType : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("EKAttendee")!
var nsObjectType : NSObject.Type = anyObjectType as! NSObject.Type
var attendee: EKParticipant = nsObjectType.init() as! EKParticipant ;

print("\(attendee)") ;
```

which results in

```
EKAttendee <0x4a948450>
email               : (null)
isCurrentUser       : 0
replyRequested      : 0
role                : (null)
status              : (null)
type                : 0
scheduleForceSend   : 0
```

which seems to indicate there is an email member.

If I try to change the email via subscript I get the following error.

```
./create-event-in-calendar.swift:83:10: error: type 'EKParticipant' has no subscript members
attendee["email"] = "test@email.com"
```

If I try to change the email via a member I get the following error.

```
./create-event-in-calendar.swift:83:2: error: value of type 'EKParticipant' has no member 'email'
attendee.email = "test@email.com"
```

Any ideas on how to change email within the attendee object?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I ended up just adding the events without attendees. It was for a database report. I'd code it object c if I needed the attendee information.